# Regex to find double parenthesis using Notepad++

Tags: regex, match, notepad++

I am trying to find sentences that has opening and closing parenthesis within another one, like (text (more)) .  I tried something like the following `\([^\)].*?\(` - `\(.*\(` - `((?:\([^]]*\))+)` to match at least the first two `((` but it's not right, and I think it would be better to match something like ((.*)) with a lazy quantifier, and it should work with anything in the text between the `(())`, even if it is divided between lines like in html codes. etc.

Example text:

> know that I can (negate) group of chars aknow that I can negate group of chars aknow that I can negate group of chars aknow that I can
> negate group of chars aknow (that I can negate) group of **((chars
> aknow that))** I can negate group of chars aknow that I can negate
> **(group (of chars) (aknow) that)** I can negate group of chars aknow that I can negate group of chars aknow that I can negate group of
> chars aknow that I can negate group of chars aknow that I can negate
> group of chars aknow that I can negate group of chars a know that I
> can negate **((group  of chars a know that I can negate))** group of
> chars a
>
> aknow that I can negate group of **(chars aknow that I can negat#e g[roup] of chars**
>
> **aknow that aknow that I can negate group of (chars aknow))** that I can negate group of chars aknow that

Comment: You may use `\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)` or `\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)+` if you want to match any 1+ `)`s on the right.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks, but that find single ones too..

Comment: Try `\([^()]*(?:(?R)[^()]*)+\)` then.

Comment: You can try this `\(.*?\(.*?\)\)`  https://regex101.com/r/8ctSO8/1/

Comment: @ Code Maniac Thanks, but that finds starting from the first one the has only one `( )`

Comment: Could you please bold your expected matches in the question? Also, please let know what your final goal is: replace something, remove, or just find?

Comment: @Mike first one end at the end of paragraph. will you please add a sample matched output from the input.

Comment: I edited marked the example, and this `\([^()]*(?:(?R)[^()]*)+\)` works well.. thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\([^()]*(?:(?R)[^()]*)+\)
```

Settings:

[image]

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(?:(?R)[^()]*)+` - 1 or more repetitions of

  - `(?R)` - the whole pattern is recursed
  - `[^()]*` -  0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

[image]

Comment: Great,, thanks..  Do you know what edit needed to that regex to make it work with grepWin too?  Because I tried with it and it got nothing.

Comment: Cheers mate +1 for detailed answer :)

Comment: @Mike I see [GrepWin uses Boost](https://tools.stefankueng.com/regexhelp.html), same as Notepad++. It should work the same.

Comment: I installed it, I will have a look.

Comment: I have not yet understood why that happens. Probably, some quirk with the Boost engine (current implemented Boost library is 1.68).

Comment: Do you suggest I try to find an older version of grepWin?  I also thought what should work on NP++ should work with it.  That's why I didn't mention it in the original question.  Or do you know any good similar programs like grepWin do search same way in bulk and support the same query?

Comment: I don't want to replace, I want links to actual files like so I can click on them and open to check in another editor other than NP++.  I will use this regex to find the files that match the query.

Comment: @Mike Then use *Find in Files* in Notepad++.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but then I have to copy each path and then paste it to open with the default program (html for example) for thousands of files, instead of just clicking in them using grepWin.