# Same regex not working between grepWin and Notepad++

Tags: regex, grep, notepad++

In Notepad++ I use the following regex `(([^()](?:(?R)[^()])+))` to search for sentences with more than one parentheses ([example text here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801758/regex-to-find-double-parenthesis-using-notepad)). However in grepWin it brings "no match" through the Regex Text, although NP++ and grepWin use Boost.  Can't find the exact difference to make that regex work with grepWin.

Comment: Maybe grepWin doesn't support recursive `(?R)` regex?

Comment: Is there a workaround?